# How to know that my ubuntu system is clear from bad file?

Tags: security, system

How to know that my system have been accessed through by backdoor and how to know there is rootkit, malware or trojan in my ubuntu system.

Comment: please edit your question to clarify and specify exactly what you mean -- right now, this is incredibly vague.

Comment: Can you please add a little more detail? (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the open source anti virus program `clamav` to scan your computer

For a command line version

```
sudo apt-get install clamav
```

To scan your PC first update the data base

```
sudo freshclam
```

Then run a scan

```
sudo clamscam
```

If you prefer a `gui` install `clamtk` instead, it is the same anti virus but with a `gui`

```
sudo apt-get install clamtk
```

[image]

As pointed out by @ThomasW in the comments, there is no guaranteed way to find all opened backdoors, the recommended course of action to take, if you know you have been infected, is to "nuke it from orbit", meaning delete and reinstall Ubuntu to make sure it is gone.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! If this answer helped you please press the check mark on the left to say thanks and let others easily find the information, if not please feedback.

Comment: This is not a guarantee however - it is still possible to have a backdoor opened and not detected by ClamAV

Comment: @ThomasW. This is true, if know a more reliable method, please do make an answer, I would be interested to see it myself :)

Comment: The tried and true Nuke It From Orbit approach comes to mind, mainly because if you believe you are infected you should get rid of the infection completely because of subsequent secondary infects caused by the first breach and such (no real way to know what was affected)...

Comment: @ThomasW. Do you mind if I add this to the answer? I will credit you for the information of course.

Comment: Just curious if it's a typo or has a deeper reason: Why do you install `clamav` with `apt` and `clamtk` with `apt-get`?

Comment: Sorry @ByteCommander that is a typo :) Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @markkirby go ahead

Comment: Thanks, I will look in your profile and give you a couple of upvotes for the info :) @ThomasW.

Comment: @markkirby don't need the upvotes but okay

Comment: Thank you for your answer before, i scanned for bad file using "chkrootkit"  got warning and i found "gvfs" directory under /run/user/1000 which it's directory (gvfs) has access right: ??? (Question Mark), owner: ?, size of file also ?. when i scanned using "clamav" just appear notice "no files were scanned". Do you have same directory (gvfs) with me ?

Comment: Yes I have `gvfs` directory, it is empty.